# What should I know or ask when negotiating a contract?

Tags: negotiation, contracting

I responded to an RFP (request for proposal) for a contracting position.

The RFP specified a 1 year contract, with a possibility of a second year.

I have reason to believe there's a reasonable chance that this position could transition to a full-time employed position.

In the proposal I sent, I mentioned a salary figure as my proposed contract compensation.

I'm a little worried that I may have come in a bit low; the figure is roughly 50% more than what I currently make in my full time position (which I would have to leave to take the contract position).

I've contracted before, but either through an agency, or for short term side work at an hourly rate.

For reference,  I'm in the US, and I will be able to switch to my wife's health insurance policy (which is slightly more out-of-pocket cost for me, but it's a vastly better policy).

The interview seemed to go well.  If they do decide that they want to hire me, what can I expect to happen?  What questions do I need to ask?

Main concerns I have are:

- salaried vs hourly compensation
- sick/vacation time
- how taxes will be handled

Comment: If this question is too broad or opinion based, I can edit to focus on specific areas. However, this is all new to me, so I'm really trying to get a feeling in general of what to expect,  and what to watch out for.

Comment: RFP mystery abbreviation?

Comment: Request for Proposal

Comment: @zipzit request for proposal.  I've edited to define it.

Comment: If you have medical coverage from another source, a 1099 contract employee has some nice other benefits.  If you are an employee, you can't claim mileage.  If  you are an independent contractor working at a facility, your mileage from home to that office is deductible, etc...

Comment: what are your questions about sick/vacation time and salaried vs hourly?  As a contractor, you're by definition hourly unless salaried was specified.   And as for sick time, you typically don't get paid when you don't work. Same goes for vacation.

Comment: @ChristopherEstep my proposal specified an annual salary, which is what I would prefer.  I would like to negotiate salaried compensation, sick and vacation time, and even having the company deduct and handle the taxes, if any of those things seem realistic.

Comment: @Beofett the problem with that is you're basically asking to be an employee. Contractors invoice their customer (which they would be to you) and you're responsible for your own taxes, etc. Now you COULD negotiate "salary" which for a contractor would be a flat amount every week, 2 weeks, month, etc.  You'd basically be on retainer. Personally, I'd rather bill hourly.  It keeps them from abusing you.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere you cannot "renegotiate" what has not yet been negotiated.  The proposal had a dollar amount for one year, not an hourly rate. There are no details about anything beyond the requested sum.  Nothing about disbursement schedules, expectations of work schedule, or anything else.  I assumed all of that would be finalized during negotiations if they offered me the role.  Was that an invalid assumption?

Comment: And if asking about attempting to renogitate the terms after they've already been set is the reason for the downvote, please point out how I can clarify the question, because that is very definitely **not** what I'm asking.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere the RFP outlined more than 20 rough areas of responsibility, with not nearly enough detail to provide the "comprehensive pricing proposal for services that may be rendered under this contract" in a format I felt comfortable with beyond an annual figure.  In retrospect, I probably should have specified an hourly rate, but it seems my pricing didn't get me rejected out of hand.

Answer (score 2):

Don't think of it as a possible full-time position or plan for that.  It's a contract. Even if a manager tells you off-the-record "we'd like for this to be permanent at some point" you have to remember that until you actually get an offer for that, it's still a contract. Contracts end.

As for your taxes, you'll need to pay your own social security and any state and local taxes.  There are other things you'll need to pay as well.  For that you need to talk to an accountant qualified to advise you on these things, if you don't know one already.

You may have indeed come in a bit low but at least it's more than what you're getting.  Unfortunately, your offer is your offer and that told them that it is what you'll accept.  They really have no incentive to renegotiate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can probably assume that it's a W-2 contract.  And depending on the environment you're in, contract vs fulltime may not make a huge difference except for who sends you a check every two weeks.

Comment: If it's not, the recruiter has more at risk by not disclosing that up front, because far more people will be 1099-averse than W-2 averse.  The recruiter would be foolish to go thru the interview process, get the candidate hooked, and then have the candidate bail because of a sudden announcement that it's 1099.

Comment: To clarify, there is no recruiter. The RFP was issued directly by the company on their website.  I replied directly to it.  I honestly have no idea if it's w-2 or 1099, which sounds like the type of information I should find out if I'm offered the position  (which is why I asked the question, after all).

Comment: As someone who knew nothing about the distinction between a 1099 contract and a w2 contract, I found this article quite helpful: http://www.fool.com/investing/general/2015/05/20/1099-vs-w2-which-is-preferable-for-employers-and-e.aspx